# What is the recommended path to place flutter SDK on MacOS?

Tags: flutter

The installation instructions omit any explicit path:

```
$ git clone -b beta https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
$ export PATH=`pwd`/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't really matter. 
Use a place where you have proper permissions.

I think `~/flutter` is quite common.

Answer (score 10):

I am not a fan of polluting the home directory. I run my flutter SDK from `$HOME/Library/Flutter` (by analogy with `/Library/Java`).

Answer (score 0):

I put flutter in `/Users/Shared/flutter` with the executables at `/Users/Shared/flutter/bin`... I don't like adding extraneous folders/files to system paths like `**/Library`, and adding it to places like my home folder, `/usr/local/bin`, etc, just didn't seem right either. But putting it in /Users/Shared seemed like exactly the right spot for it.